# root/jailbreak detection for ionic hybrid mobile app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working on ionic mobile app with Angularjs, and we have added root detector by using **cordova-plugin-root-detection** and a jailbreak detector by using **cordova-plugin-jailbreak-detection**. But now for more security, we need to add another root detectors.

Is there any plugins / way to do it rather than the plugins that we have already used & mentioned above?

Thanks.

Comment: Other that *all* of these "root detectors" can and have been successfully bypassed?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for both Android and iOS, use [cordova-plugin-iroot](https://github.com/WuglyakBolgoink/cordova-plugin-iroot).

If you want to check deeply inside Android device you can(I will suggest to) add additional plugin [cordova-plugin-android-rootbeer](https://github.com/karandpr/cordova-plugin-android-rootbeer). It will be better to use `isRootedWithoutBusyBoxCheck` function present in this plugin.

Later one doesn't catches bypass done by Magisk. This has been solved in original plugin [Rootbeer](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer). This should be soon availalble in it too.

Both plugins mentioned above utilizes other plugins and improvements being done constantly in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following plugin to check if device is rooted or not 
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#isdevicerooted